# Reditect main domain to https, but not subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https, dns

I have a website say **example.com** and a SSL for www.example.com. 
I want - if anyone goes to **example.com** or **www.example.com**, he is redirected to **https://www.example.com/.**

But if he goes to **sub.example.com**, he should not be redirected to https, i.e. stay on to http.

I've gone through various answers on StackOverflow, but could not configure it out. Currently, I'm using the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

This redirects **sub.example.com** to https://www.example.com/sub/, which I don't desire to.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You want to add an extra condition that checks the current hostname. You can do this with the `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Not working! when going to example.com, it stays at example.com only!

Comment: What do you mean?! example.com is not www.example.com, so of course it doesn't force https.